# Best practices to scripting SQL Server 2008 schema changes

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, version-control, scripting

Currently, we are maintaining table and proc changes in TFS.

Stored procedures include a create proc statement and a drop proc statement:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('ResponseTracking_Get_Requests') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE ResponseTracking_Get_Requests
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ResponseTracking_Get_Requests]
 ( @RequestID int = null)

 AS

 SELECT 
    RequestID, 
    Category, 
    Title, 
    DateReceived, 
    Source, 
    ResponseRequired, 
    ResponseDateDue, 
    ApprovalLevelRequired, 
    FollowUpDate, 
    Request, 
    Status, 
    Notes, 
    ClosedDate, 
    EmployeeID, 
    CreationDateTime

FROM dbo.Request
Where (@RequestID IS NULL OR Request.RequestID = @RequestID)
```

With Initial Table changes, I have included a check if the table object exists:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('Approval') IS NULL
      CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Approval](
        [RequestID] [int] NULL,
        [EmployeeID] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
        [CreationDateTime] [datetime2](0) NULL,
        [Level] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [DateSent] [datetime2](0) NULL,
        [DateApproved] [datetime2](0) NULL,
        [Comments] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [SSMA_TimeStamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I need help figuring out how to script any modification/alter to a table after initial create statements. Any recommendation for my proc scripts would appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When if comes to adding new columns to your table, you might try something along the lines of:

```
if not exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c where c.TABLE_NAME='Foo' and c.COLUMN_NAME='Bar')
    alter table Foo add Bar varchar(50) not null
go
```

This will check for the existence of the new column in your table and only add it in if the column is not found in the database schema. You can reverse the logic if your want to drop a column.

If you're altering a column definition then just execute your ALTER TABLE Foo ALTER COLUMN Bar ... statement every time - there's no real advantage in checking the schema to see if the change is required.

One other point to mention: it's generally not a good idea to drop and re-create stored procedures as you'll lose any security that's been configured for them (grant execute, for example). I've always found this pattern to be a better option:

```
if not exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES r where r.ROUTINE_NAME='getFoo' and r.ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE')
       exec('create procedure [getFoo] as select [Now]=getdate()')
go

alter procedure [getFoo](@someParam int) as
    SELECT * 
    FROM [Foo]
    WHERE SomeValue=@someParam
go
```

Doing it this way means that the stored procedure only gets created once, but is updated every time you run the script thereafter.

Comment: No problem at all - happy to help out. Just don't forget to mark the question as answered if you're happy with it so as others can benefit as well (it also helps me on the long road to getting a decent rating here ;)